# query objects where array field does not include value

Tags: rest, parse-platform

Trying to implement a country blacklist, but it's not clear to me how to query for a negative match on an array field using the [Parse REST API](https://parse.com/docs/rest#queries-arrays). The countries being an array key.

```
blacklistCountries = [ "CN", "KP" ]
```

Is there something like `$not`?

```
where={ blacklistCountries: { $not: "CN" } }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is `$ne` (not equal to) as described in [Query Constraints](https://parse.com/docs/rest#queries-constraints):

```
where={"blacklistCountries":{"$ne":"CN"}}
```